# ignite table max column count(may be 1000plus)

Tags: ignite

> I want to export hive table to **ignite**,the table column count may be **1000** plus in the future.
>   Is ignite suitable for this situation?
>   thanks for you reply.

Comment: IFAIK Ignite is suitable for big number of columns, even for thousands.

Comment: thanks @KonstantinDudkov